# Проблемы с версткой (:hover, :active)

Tags: html, css, hover

Здравствуйте. При вёрстке формы с инпутом и кнопками появилась проблема: при наведении на label активируется :hover кнопки "-", хотя он прописан конкретно самой кнопке. С кнопкой "+" такого не наблюдается, :hover срабатывает, когда ему и следует. Также при нажатии на кнопку "+" активируется :active у кнопки "-". Уже пару часов сижу и не втыкаю, где ошибка...

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.search-heading-form {
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 154px;
  height: 78px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 1, 1, 0.2);
}

.form-people {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
 }

.form-people input {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 39px;
  width: 114px;
  height: 38px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.form-people button {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 14px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #a9a9a9;
}

.form-people button:hover { color: #000000; }

.form-people button:active { color: #81b3d2; }

.form-people button:focus { outline: none; }

.form-people .icon-minus {
  top: 12px;
  right: 88px;
}

.form-people .icon-plus {
  top: 12px;
  right: 14px;
}
```

```html
<form class="search-heading-form">
  <label class="form-people">
    <button class="icon-minus" type="button">-</button>
    <input type="number" value="2">
    <button class="icon-plus" type="button">+</button>
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно изменить label на div

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.search-heading-form {
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 154px;
  height: 78px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 1, 1, 0.2);
}

.form-people {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
 }

.form-people input {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 39px;
  width: 114px;
  height: 38px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.form-people button {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 14px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #a9a9a9;
}

.form-people button:hover { color: #000000; }

.form-people button:active { color: #81b3d2; }

.form-people button:focus { outline: none; }

.form-people .icon-minus {
  top: 12px;
  right: 88px;
}

.form-people .icon-plus {
  top: 12px;
  right: 14px;
}
```

```html
<form class="search-heading-form">
  <div class="form-people">
    <button class="icon-minus" type="button">-</button>
    <input type="number" value="2">
    <button class="icon-plus" type="button">+</button>
  </div>
</form>
```